# mysql syntax error 1064 on create procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-error-1064

Hi I have created a table and now creating a stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p_order_insert (in in_agent_id Varchar(10),in in_rate_city varchar(15),in in_sendername varchar(50),in in_senderaddress1 varchar(50),in in_senderaddress2 varchar(50),in in_senderaddress3 varchar(50),in in_senderaddress4 varchar(50),in in_sendercity varchar(50),in in_senderstate varchar(50),in in_senderpostcode varchar(10),in in_sendercountry varchar(15),in in_receivername varchar(50),in in_receiveraddress1 varchar(50),in in_receiveraddress2 varchar(50),in in_receiveraddress3 varchar(50),in in_receiveraddress4 varchar(50),in in_receivercity varchar(50),in in_receiverstate varchar(50),in in_receiverpostcode varchar(10),in in_receivercountry varchar(15),in in_item1_description varchar(80),in in_item2_description varchar(80),in in_item3_description varchar(80),in in_item4_description varchar(80),in in_item5_description varchar(80),in in_item6_description varchar(80),in in_item1_quantity int,in in_item2_quantity int,in in_item3_quantity int,in in_item4_quantity int,in in_item5_quantity int,in in_item6_quantity int,in in_item1_weight double,in in_item2_weight double,in in_item3_weight double,in in_item4_weight double,in in_item5_weight double,in in_item6_weight double,in in_item1_value double,in in_item2_value double,in in_item3_value double,in in_item4_value double,in in_item5_value double,in in_item6_value double,in in_order_status Varchar(10),in in_total_price double,in in_agent_commission double,in in_payment_received Varchar(10), OUT out_awb_ref_id Varchar (10))   BEGIN
INSERT INTO hvp_order_master (agent_id, rate_city, sendername, senderaddress1, senderaddress2, senderaddress3, senderaddress4, sendercity, senderstate, senderpostcode, sendercountry, receivername, receiveraddress1, receiveraddress2, receiveraddress3, receiveraddress4, receivercity, receiverstate, receiverpostcode, receivercountry, item1_description, item2_description, item3_description, item4_description, item5_description, item6_description, item1_quantity, item2_quantity, item3_quantity, item4_quantity, item5_quantity, item6_quantity, item1_weight, item2_weight, item3_weight, item4_weight, item5_weight, item6_weight, item1_value, item2_value, item3_value, item4_value, item5_value, item6_value, order_status, total_price, agent_commission, payment_received) 
VALUES 
(in_agent_id, in_rate_city, in_sendername, in_senderaddress1, in_senderaddress2, in_senderaddress3, in_senderaddress4, in_sendercity, in_senderstate, in_senderpostcode, in_sendercountry, in_receivername, in_receiveraddress1, in_receiveraddress2, in_receiveraddress3, in_receiveraddress4, in_receivercity, in_receiverstate, in_receiverpostcode, in_receivercountry, in_item1_description, in_item2_description, in_item3_description, in_item4_description, in_item5_description, in_item6_description, in_item1_quantity, in_item2_quantity, in_item3_quantity, in_item4_quantity, in_item5_quantity, in_item6_quantity, in_item1_weight, in_item2_weight, in_item3_weight, in_item4_weight, in_item5_weight, in_item6_weight, in_item1_value, in_item2_value, in_item3_value, in_item4_value, in_item5_value, in_item6_value, in_order_status, in_total_price, in_agent_commission, in_payment_received); END;;
```

However, I am getting

> ## 1064 - Erreur de syntaxe prÃ¨s de '' Ã  la ligne 6  there is no such issue which I can see.

Could someone help?

Comment: Thats a SLAB OF CODE. Would you like to format it so we can read it please. I was going to do it but there is a LOT OF CODE THERE. _If you want any help that is_

Comment: Format it so that ___Ligne 6___ is ___Line 6 in your code___ As currently there are only 4 lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you included the `DELIMITER` wrapper it saves, like below.

In addition I am sure you have a poor schema design.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS p_order_insert;
DELIMITER $
CREATE PROCEDURE p_order_insert 
(in in_agent_id Varchar(10),
in in_rate_city varchar(15),
in in_sendername varchar(50),
in in_senderaddress1 varchar(50),
in in_senderaddress2 varchar(50),
in in_senderaddress3 varchar(50),
in in_senderaddress4 varchar(50),
in in_sendercity varchar(50),
in in_senderstate varchar(50),
in in_senderpostcode varchar(10),
in in_sendercountry varchar(15),
in in_receivername varchar(50),
in in_receiveraddress1 varchar(50),
in in_receiveraddress2 varchar(50),
in in_receiveraddress3 varchar(50),
in in_receiveraddress4 varchar(50),
in in_receivercity varchar(50),
in in_receiverstate varchar(50),
in in_receiverpostcode varchar(10),
in in_receivercountry varchar(15),
in in_item1_description varchar(80),
in in_item2_description varchar(80),
in in_item3_description varchar(80),
in in_item4_description varchar(80),
in in_item5_description varchar(80),
in in_item6_description varchar(80),
in in_item1_quantity int,
in in_item2_quantity int,
in in_item3_quantity int,
in in_item4_quantity int,
in in_item5_quantity int,
in in_item6_quantity int,
in in_item1_weight double,
in in_item2_weight double,
in in_item3_weight double,
in in_item4_weight double,
in in_item5_weight double,
in in_item6_weight double,
in in_item1_value double,
in in_item2_value double,
in in_item3_value double,
in in_item4_value double,
in in_item5_value double,
in in_item6_value double,
in in_order_status Varchar(10),
in in_total_price double,
in in_agent_commission double,
in in_payment_received Varchar(10), 
OUT out_awb_ref_id Varchar (10))   
BEGIN
INSERT INTO hvp_order_master (agent_id, rate_city, sendername, senderaddress1, senderaddress2, 
senderaddress3, senderaddress4, sendercity, senderstate, senderpostcode, sendercountry, 
receivername, receiveraddress1, receiveraddress2, receiveraddress3, receiveraddress4, 
receivercity, receiverstate, receiverpostcode, receivercountry, item1_description, 
item2_description, item3_description, item4_description, item5_description, 
item6_description, item1_quantity, item2_quantity, item3_quantity, item4_quantity, 
item5_quantity, item6_quantity, item1_weight, item2_weight, item3_weight, item4_weight, 
item5_weight, item6_weight, item1_value, item2_value, item3_value, item4_value, item5_value, 
item6_value, order_status, total_price, agent_commission, payment_received) 
SELECT  
 in_agent_id, in_rate_city, in_sendername, in_senderaddress1, in_senderaddress2, 
in_senderaddress3, in_senderaddress4, in_sendercity, in_senderstate, in_senderpostcode, 
in_sendercountry, in_receivername, in_receiveraddress1, in_receiveraddress2, in_receiveraddress3, 
in_receiveraddress4, in_receivercity, in_receiverstate, in_receiverpostcode, in_receivercountry, 
in_item1_description, in_item2_description, in_item3_description, in_item4_description, 
in_item5_description, in_item6_description, in_item1_quantity, in_item2_quantity, in_item3_quantity,
 in_item4_quantity, in_item5_quantity, in_item6_quantity, in_item1_weight, in_item2_weight, 
 in_item3_weight, in_item4_weight, in_item5_weight, in_item6_weight, in_item1_value, in_item2_value, 
 in_item3_value, in_item4_value, in_item5_value, in_item6_value, in_order_status, in_total_price, 
 in_agent_commission, in_payment_received; 
 END$$
 DELIMITER ;
```

The need for a `DELIMITER` is dependent on which client-side tool you use. For PHPMyAdmin, it is not needed typically if ever.

With MySQL Workbench it is.

Comment: Thanks Drew, but still getting error on #1064 - Erreur de syntaxe prÃ¨s de '' Ã  la ligne 72

Comment: How about now. Just waking up and needed coffee

Comment: Did you change anything?

Comment: yeah the select stmt in the middle and some parens

Comment: Well it now works. Issue was with browser based MYSQL.. Thanks DREW

Answer (score 0):

Add `DELIMITER @@` to the start. Also, at the end of your code you have the `;` twice. `END;;` 1 is enough.

```
DELIMITER @@
CREATE PROCEDURE...
END@@
DELIMITER;
```